# After creating wffm form in sitecore 9.0 update 1, how do we publish it?

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms

We create a sitecore form and then add to a webpage. But i am not sure after creating a WFFM form, how do we add it to a webpage?  Please mention steps.

> Running sitecore version: sitecore 9.0 update 1

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that in Sitecore 9, it already comes with Sitecore Forms pre-baked into it. Sitecore Forms has a much better ui and is gonna replace wffm. I suggest you look at that instead of wffm.

Now, if for some reasons you wanna still use wffm, when you install wffm package, it adds a sublayout and a rendering component in your sitecore. You can add the forms component( either sublayout or rendering depending on whether you using web forms or mvc) to your page the same way like adding a sitecore component in the presentation details.

There are more details in the sitecore docs. It is written for 8.2 but its the same steps for 9.0 setup.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/web-forms-for-marketers/en/insert-a-web-form-directly-on-a-web-page.html

Comment: What is that step 6 and 7 hereand how to do this. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/web-forms-for-marketers/en/reinstall-the-web-forms-for-marketers-module.html

Comment: @Manjesh, I have not done a reinstall of wffm before, but from what it looks like, step 6  and 7 is just related to step 2 and 3 where you restore your earlier backups if there are stuffs you wanted to retain before reinstalling. If you have more questions, I suggest u create a new question for it as it seems unrelated.